# How to disassociate .gitignote file type from notepad in Windows10?

Tags: registry, windows-10, gitignore, file-association

Well, keeping it straight, I accidentaly associated `.gitignore` to notepad.
Now it won't work.

I already tried some solutions that is deleting `.gitignore` folder from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and also deleted the `.gitignore` folder in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

Neither of these worked for me. I'm in windows 10.
I don't know much about registry and if my attempts to solve this problem may have a bad influence on my system.

Answer (score 1):

- Open **regedit** (Win Key + R, type: regedit).
- On the top menu click on **Edit** > **Find...**
- Type: **gitignore**
- Right click **Delete** those keys/folders you find. (2 in my case).
- **Reboot** so changes are reflected.